# Why does stream parallel() not use all available threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream, forkjoinpool

I tried to run 100 **Sleep** tasks in parallel using Java8(1.8.0_172) stream.parallel() submitted inside a custom ForkJoinPool with 100+ threads available. Each task would **sleep** for 1s. I expected the whole work would finish after ~1s, given the 100 sleeps could be done in parallel. However I observe a runtime of 7s.

```java
    @Test
    public void testParallelStream() throws Exception {
        final int REQUESTS = 100;
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = null;
        try {
            // new ForkJoinPool(256): same results for all tried values of REQUESTS
            forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(REQUESTS);
            forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {

                IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, REQUESTS);
                final List<String> result = stream.parallel().mapToObj(i -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("request " + i);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        return Integer.toString(i);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                // assertThat(result).hasSize(REQUESTS);
            }).join();
        } finally {
            if (forkJoinPool != null) {
                forkJoinPool.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
```

With output indicating ~16 stream elements are executed before a pause of 1s, then another ~16 and so on. So it seems even though the forkjoinpool was created with 100 threads, only ~16 get used.

This pattern emerges as soon as I use more than 23 threads:

```
1-23 threads: ~1s
24-35 threads: ~2s
36-48 threads: ~3s
...
```

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
// Output: 4
```

Comment: What's your `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` output?

Comment: availableProcessors() == 4, I added to description

Comment: How long does the sequential execution take?

Comment: sequential takes 100s, as expected.

Comment: This question might observe the same thing (has no answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068119

Comment: This trick to make a parallel stream use a different thread pools is an undocumented implementation side effect and was not intended to work that way. So the implementation didn't care about the possibility of a different parallelism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Stream implementation’s use of the Fork/Join pool is an implementation detail, the trick to force it to use a different Fork/Join pool is undocumented as well and seems to work by accident, i.e. there’s a [hardcoded constant](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/AbstractTask.java#l97) determining the actual parallelism, depending on the default pool’s parallelism. So using a different pool was not foreseen, originally.

However, it has been recognized that using a different pool with an inappropriate target parallelism is a bug, even if this trick is not documented, see [JDK-8190974](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190974).

It has been fixed in Java 10 and backported to Java 8, update 222.

So a simple solution world be updating the Java version.

You may also change the default pool’s parallelism, e.g.

```
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "100");
```

before doing any Fork/Join activity.

But this may have unintended effects on other parallel operations.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it, you let the stream decide the parallelism of the executions.

There you have the effect that `ArrayList.parallelStream` tries to outsmart you by splitting the data up evenly, without taking the number of available threads into account. This is good for CPU-Bound operations, where it's not usefull to have more threads than CPU Cores, but is not made for processes that need to wait for IO.

Why not force-feed all your items sequentially to the ForkJoinPool, so it's forced to use all available threads?

```
        IntStream stream = IntStream.range(0, REQUESTS);
        List<ForkJoinTask<String>> results
                = stream.mapToObj(i -> forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {

            try {
                System.out.println("request " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return Integer.toString(i);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());
        results.forEach(ForkJoinTask::join);
```

This takes less than two seconds on my machine.

Comment: The point was to understand how parallel streams work, and what to look out for when writing code. So your solution is not wrong, but the question was specifically about the solution using parallel streams does not work.